# Representation of a game with simultaneous movements

Tags: game-theory

In Game Theory, can you use a tree structure to represent a game with simultaneous movements or you have to use a matrix form? In a sequential game it is logical to use a tree, as every node represents a move so by following the branches you can follow the moves one after another, but I can't see how it would be logical if it could be used in a non-sequential game. In such a game there would be 2 trees, one for player 1 staring the game and one for player 2 starting the game, but both of them would not represent the same game as in reality both players start at the same time.

Comment: I agree. In tree cannot represent a simulaneous game. But a matrix can either represent a simulaneous game or a sequential game.

Comment: You could use a tree for simultaneous movements as well; it's just that the edges would correspond to ordered pairs of moves, rather than single-player moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extensive-form game **can** represent simultaneous moves via the use of **imperfect information**, that is, the fact that two players move at the same time is captured by one of them (either of them) moving first and subsequently the other player moves **without** learning what the first player to move did. For example, the following bimatrix game:

[image]

can be represented by the following imperfect-information extensive-form game:

[image]

In this extensive-form game, player 1 moves and then player 2 moves without knowing which move player 1 chose. Note, we could as well have just had player 2 move first in the extensive-form game, and then have player 1 move second, uninformed about player 2's move. Finally, note that if we *dissolve* the non-singleton information set, then we have a commitment (aka Stackelberg) game, as follows, where now the *order of the players moving does matter*.

[image]

The pictures in this post were generated with Game Theory Explorer (http://gametheoryexplorer.org).